# Sum DLookUp in Report

Tags: ms-access, report, crosstab

I have created a report based off of a crosstab query. It is counting the number of instances that each group does a certain task and displaying the totals in the report.

On one of the reports it has to also include the budget for each group. I was able to include this by using a DLookUp toward the table and tying it back to the Groups displayed on the report. **However my issue is not being able to now sum this column of information. What can I do to fix this?**

I have tried `SUM(DLookUp("CBudget","[Contract Budget]","[CommunityGroup] = '" & [txtCommunityGroup] & "'")` and `DSUM("CBudget","[Contract Budget]","[CommunityGroup] = '" & [txtCommunityGroup] & "'")`, but neither work.

Comment: Why not just do a join on the crosstab query and the table/query with the budget?

Answer (score 0):

I finally added the column as a column heading in the crosstab and got what I needed. Thanks